# Using ETW to print time stamp on context switch

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, event-handling, etw

I am using the following code that I found on Microsoft's website. It compiles successfully and outputs a log file, as it's supposed to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define INITGUID  // Include this #define to use SystemTraceControlGuid in Evntrace.h.

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <wmistr.h>
#include <evntrace.h>

#define LOGFILE_PATH L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\My Dropbox\\Log.etl"

void wmain(void)
{

    ULONG status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    TRACEHANDLE SessionHandle = 0;
    EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES* pSessionProperties = NULL;
    ULONG BufferSize = 0;

    // Allocate memory for the session properties. The memory must
    // be large enough to include the log file name and session name,
    // which get appended to the end of the session properties structure.

    BufferSize = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES) + sizeof(LOGFILE_PATH) + sizeof(KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME);
    pSessionProperties = (EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES*) malloc(BufferSize);    
    if (NULL == pSessionProperties)
    {
        wprintf(L"Unable to allocate %d bytes for properties structure.\n", BufferSize);

        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Set the session properties. You only append the log file name
    // to the properties structure; the StartTrace function appends
    // the session name for you.

    ZeroMemory(pSessionProperties, BufferSize);
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.BufferSize = BufferSize;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.Flags = WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.ClientContext = 1; //QPC clock resolution
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.Guid = SystemTraceControlGuid; 
    pSessionProperties->EnableFlags = EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_CSWITCH;
    pSessionProperties->LogFileMode = EVENT_TRACE_FILE_MODE_CIRCULAR;
    pSessionProperties->MaximumFileSize = 5;  // 5 MB
    pSessionProperties->LoggerNameOffset = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES);
    pSessionProperties->LogFileNameOffset = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES) + sizeof(KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME); 
    StringCbCopy((LPWSTR)((char*)pSessionProperties + pSessionProperties->LogFileNameOffset), sizeof(LOGFILE_PATH), LOGFILE_PATH);

    // Create the trace session.

    status = StartTrace((PTRACEHANDLE)&SessionHandle, KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME, pSessionProperties);

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        if (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == status)
        {
            wprintf(L"The NT Kernel Logger session is already in use.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"EnableTrace() failed with %lu\n", status);
            getchar();
        }

        goto cleanup;
    }

    wprintf(L"Press any key to end trace session ");
    _getch();

cleanup:

    if (SessionHandle)
    {
        status = ControlTrace(SessionHandle, KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME, pSessionProperties, EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_STOP);

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
        {
            wprintf(L"ControlTrace(stop) failed with %lu\n", status);
        }
    }

    if (pSessionProperties)
        free(pSessionProperties);
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to modify this code to make it print a time stamp when it detects a context switch. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please post any code you have tried to make it print a time stamp on a context switch? Does it work, are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am stuck here. I can see that the StartTrace function is where the action happens, but I'm not sure how to tap into it to get what I want. I'm thinking perhaps the SessionHandle would be the way to go?